# Angular in a injected cshtml file, $compile not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

**TL;TR; is below**

I'm dealing with a huge application where everything is made super-generic to easily expend. One of the components is the dialog. Now before your answer is, use `ngInclude` or angular templates, let me explain how these work and why we would like to stick to them.

The flow of creating this dialog:

1. From somewhere in javascript a javascript function is called.
2. That constructs the container for the dialog. Position, widths, heights, gray background, etc.
3. Once that is present, a loading indicator will show up, while a GET request takes place to the back-end.
4. At the back-end Action, a view name is provided and a model.
5. This view (a .cshtml file) gets loaded into a string builder. To give you an idea of what happens, here is a piece of code where the view gets loaded.

   ```
   var sb = new StringBuilder(1);
   using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb))
   {
       .....
       var helper = new HtmlHelper(viewContext, viewDataContainer);
       using (helper.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
       {
           helper.RenderPartial(viewName, model);
       }
       return sb.ToString();
   }
   ```
6. Then the string is returned, in javascript it is eventually set as html: `diag.html(jsonResponse.data);`

Now the view that I load, contains angular elements, like `ng-controller` and brackets to show something from that controller. Here is the .cshtml:

```
@model int
<div ng-controller="dialogGridColumnSelectionController as dgc" ng-init="dgc.init(@Model)">

    <table>
        <thead>
           ...
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="col in dgc.tableColumns">
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="some" ng-value="dgc.hide"/>
            </td>
            <td>{{col.headerName}}</td>
            <td>{{col.Description}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

A few statements:

- `ng-app` was tried later, it should not be needed here because the `<body>` element already has this.
- The dialog is within the `<body>` element.
- No errors, no angular warnings.
- `{{col.headerName}}` shows exactly as how it is shown, so angular is not working.
- The controller and all the other required javascript files are already loaded on the page from where this dialog is opened. Also tried to add them here, no difference. I also tried to load angular there again, that does give me a warning that I `tried to load it more than once`. So the scripts are there.

Now I kind of doubted that this would work from the beginning, but I just want to make sure before we start a major rework of the dialogs.

So my question is, is it possible? Can a view that is initiated from `.html()` (in javascript) have angular? How do I "start" Angular? Or why is it not working with generated html?

**TL;TR and EDIT:**

After some digging, I eventually did this:

```
dialog.html(jsonResponse.data);//dialog is a created jquery element, jsonResponse.data contains the `.cshtml` content
if (options.angularCompile && options.angularScope) {//I've set them in options
    options.angularCompile(dialog)(options.angularScope);//= $compile(dialog)($scope) or $compile(dialog.contents())($scope)
}
```

From the html above, it does fire the `init` function. That function correctly loads data (from other injected factories).

```
var self = this;

this.tablePageID = 0;
this.tableColumns = [];

$scope.hello = "hii";
this.init = function (tablePageID) {
    self.tablePageID = tablePageID;
    self.tableColumns = gridTableFactory.getTableColumns(tablePageID);
}
```

But once completed and the dialog is shown, it still has no angular working.

[image: example]

Worth noting is that the `ng-repeat` has done it job at the beginning, there are no items. Looks like it compiles and forgets.

Comment: use $compile before adding html. And try to narrow your question - 99% of questions should be about backend or frontend, not both.

Comment: Eventually my question is about the front end. Angular is not available at that part in the code but tomorrow I will hack it into it and see if that helps.

Comment: I've used $compile, seems to work at first sight. It compiles, executes some controller code, successfully uses injected factories. But when the dialog is open, still the plain html is shown. angular brackets keep showing up. It kind of runs and forgets.

Comment: Please verify if the original compiled HTML isn't copied as new DOM elements when the dialog is shown. You may need to run the $compile service after the dialog is opened.

Comment: Hoi Koen, yes it's the last thing that happens. In fact, the dialog is already shown with a loading indicator. Once the cshtml is loaded, it will edit the content of the dialog. The `open` event starts with `var diag = $(this);`. The `response.data` is `.html()` applied to the existing dialog and then I `$compile` it.

Comment: Try executing `$scope.$apply();` after using the $compile. You may need to inform angular to update its bindings. Also try to avoid using jQuery directly and use `angular.element("#....")` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing `$scope.$apply();` after using the `$compile`. You may need to inform angular to update its bindings. Also try to avoid using jQuery directly and use `angular.element("#....")` instead.

Comment: ugh, I did `$apply()` inside the angular controller, an digest was already busy it said, so I assumed it was not needed. Didn't need `angular.element()` though for this to work.